# What's the extreme value distribution of log normals?

Tags: pr.probability

Take $X_i \sim \exp(N(0,1)), i=1,\ldots,n$ be an iid sequence. I'm looking at $Z = \min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, and want to find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $(Z-b_n)/a_n$ converges to one of the extreme value distributions.

Comment: What do you get if you take exp of a variable distributed as the extreme distribution for a normal distribution?

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes it much easier. I forgot that $\exp$ is monotone, I was being dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference, it was rather obscure: Singpurwalla, Nozer D. “Extreme Values from a Lognormal Law with Applications to Air Pollution Problems.” Technometrics 14, no. 3 (1972): 703–11.

Comment: Even this is for just the maximum though.